# Child controller fires JSON.parse from parent

Tags: angularjs, json

In my app I have a ui-router state  `home.container-big` and that state has a nested state `home.container-big.container-big-trailer`.

In the `home.container-big` state I return a value in the form of a string. For my `movie-info.html` template I need to change the string value into a object. So I use `JSON.parse`.

```
.state('home.container-big',{
  params: {
    value: null
  },
  url: '',
  views: {
    "container-big":{
      templateUrl: '../assets/angular-app/templates/_movie-info.html',
      controller: function($scope, $stateParams, $state) {
        $scope.movie = JSON.parse($stateParams.value);
        $scope.movie = $stateParams.value;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

In the `home.container-big.container-big-trailer` state I return a string value and place the data in `$scope.trailer_link` so I can use the scope in the `_container-trailer` template.

```
.state('home.container-big.container-big-trailer',{
  params: {
    value: null
  },
  url: '',
  views: {
    "youtube_trailer":{
      templateUrl: '../assets/angular-app/templates/_container-trailer.html',
      controller: function($scope, $stateParams, $state) {
        $scope.trailer_link = $stateParams.value);
        console.log ($scope.trailer_link)
      }
    }
  }
})
```

My problem here is that the `$stateParams.value` inside the `home.container-big.container-big-trailer` also goes through the `JSON.parse` from the parent state `home.container-big`. Which causes the error,

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token R
  at Object.parse (native)
```

Because if I remove the `JSON.parse` from my router controller all the code works fine but there are some problems with data inside templates.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completion, the problem here is the double definition of `$stateParams.value` in both states. Once I changed `value` to `movie-info` in the parent state, and ofcourse changed the paramater in the template to correspond it worked.